# Asterisk FastAGI Record File

Tags: asterisk

I have an inbound route defined for a local phone number that terminates to a dial plan which sends the call to a FastAGI.

When the call is answered by the FastAGI I then call the Record File command with 4 minute timeout, and silence detection disabled recording in wav file format.

However the maximum record time is only 90 seconds instead of the 4 minute I specified. However when I call the dial plan directly without using the local call it works just fine.

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Asterisk version is 11.5, I tried upgrading to the latest but the issue is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Please use following:

1) in logger.conf add console=>debug

2) connect to asterisk via asterisk -r|tee /tmp/debug.log

3) enable debug via

```
asterisk -r
agi set debug on
core set debug 5
```

After that call, wait 4+ minutes, press ctrl-c and see in debug file what you have.

Most likly silence detection invoked.

There is no differnce between Record command in dialplan and Record command issues by AGI,really.

Comment: Following your advice here are the results:
AGI Tx >> agi_priority: 1
AGI Tx >> agi_enhanced: 0.0
AGI Tx >> agi_accountcode: 
AGI Tx >> agi_threadid: -1238303856
AGI Rx << ANSWER
AGI Tx >> 200 result=0
AGI Rx << RECORD FILE "vm_test%d" "wav" "" 240000 -1 BEEP s=0
AGI Tx >> 200 result=-1 (hangup) endpos=245440
AGI Tx >> HANGUP
AGI Tx >> HANGUP
AGI Tx >> agi_request: hangup.agi
AGI Tx >> agi_channel: SIP/carrier-0000013c
AGI Tx >> agi_language: en
AGI Tx >> agi_type: SIP
AGI Tx >> agi_uniqueid: 1408462771.576
AGI Tx >> agi_version: 11.5.0

Comment: it is not debug. debug is thosands of lines. maybe you need do logger reload or restart. But from this trace it seams like hangup was from other side.